# How to set Google Cloud Function to return response when timeout

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-functions

I have cloud function that stuck forever and give no response to the caller, can I force it to return error response when timeout happen?

Comment: I am not sure it is directly possible, as it might contradict to a paradigm of how things work with cloud functions in GCP. From my point of view, it might be worth to refactor the cloud function under discussion, or to think about an alternative solution.

Comment: Can you have a look at this [Documentation](https://cloud.google.com/functions/docs/configuring/timeout#set-timeout).

Answer (score 3):

When a timeout happen, it means the network communication is cut. If you have a look to your logs, you can see the request processing continuing on your instance until the instance is offloaded.

Therefore, Cloud Functions never know/detect a loss of network communication, and can't send a response when the timeout happens.

Thus, you should reconsider your design (maybe stop the process and send a response 10s before the timeout), or change/update the service type used (use Cloud Functions gen2 or Cloud Run (Cloud Functions gen2 is based on Cloud Run) -> The timeout is expended to 60 minutes)

Or you can handle the issue on client side: if you have no answer from the service you can infer a timeout. Not the ideal solution because there are lot of cases where the network connection can break.

Comment: interesting, previously i thought GCP able to return default response cause I assume they able to know when timeout happen.